# How to display a float variable in a file?

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to save the result of a division between two integers into a variable, and to display it in a file. But it's not working with **%f**.

And I don't know why, but with these two tests I have not the same result :

Code (C) :

```
int x1 = 830, y1 = 622;
int x2 = 540, y2 = 300;

float a = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2);

// test 1
fprintf(file, "test 1 : \n\n");

fprintf(file, "a = (%d - %d) / (%d - %d)    \n", y1, y2, x1, x2);
fprintf(file, "a = %d / %d                  \n", y1 - y2, x1 - x2);
fprintf(file, "a = %f                     \n\n", (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2));

// test 2
fprintf(file, "test 2 : \n\n");

fprintf(file, "a = %f \n\n", a);
```

Result (in my file) :

```
test 1 : 

a = (622 - 300) / (830 - 540)   
a = 322 / 290                   
a = 0.000000                      

test 2 : 

a = 1.000000
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to say:

```
fprintf(file, "a = %f", (float)(y1 - y2) / (float)(x1 - x2))
//                      ^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^
```

That way you perform floating point arithmetic. Otherwise you're doing *integer* arithmetic.

Comment: Ok thanks ! But with the "test 2" I'm trying to display the variable "a" which is a float, but in the file I can't display the exact value...

Comment: @bob12 When you compute `a`, the same issue exists: `float a = (float)(y1 - y2) / (float)(x1 - x2);`

Answer (score 1):

(my response concern a part of the problem), You don't get the expected result cause: C calculate the value of division  int/int and assign the result to an int, so even if "a" is a float, you get 0.000 in a division like ( 1/2 ). the intuitive solution is declare all variables as float. hope it helps.